# imageview animated gif show only static

Tags: java, android, xml, eclipse, image

i have this code that show banner in view but only show static image even its an animsted gif, how to make this work on animated gif.

java code

```
  ImageLoader.getInstance().displayImage(ConstValue.CONTENTS_IMAGE+"big/"+companyMap.get("banner"), imgthumb, options, animateFirstListener);
```

xml code

```
            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/img_thumb"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:scaleType="fitCenter"
                android:src="@drawable/thumb_bg" />
```

Comment: use `android.graphics.Movie`

Comment: HOW TO USE IT ?

Answer (score 2):

you can use [Glide](https://github.com/bumptech/glide) to show gif animations in ImageView. usage:

```
Glide.with(context).load(YOUR_IMAGE_URL).asGif().crossFade().into(YOUR_IMAGE_VIEW);
```

Comment: i get ERRORS FOR THAT , IS THERE ANOTHER WAY